# How-to Keep an Android Activity Running when hitting the back key

Tags: android, android-activity, back, android-homebutton

I have an activity that essentially launches a CountDownTimer.  I need this to continue running while using other Android apps, such as Gmail, and media players etc.

When I hit the back button, my Activity seems to quit.  What do I need to do to keep it running when the user clicks the back/home keys etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Activities are not supposed to be doing anything when they are not visible. They are basically UI components.

You should be looking into [services](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html). These can run as a background process nd contain no UI.

Comment: This is what I was thinking, but I still need to return the remaining time (in millis) which is formatted into Hours, mins, and secs to the UI.  I had little luck accomplishing this.

Comment: I was trying to put the method that creates and starts the counter into a service and have a button start the service.  It's my understanding that services are not supposed to have UI access, so I'm unsure of how to display the timer's remaining time to the user if running it in a service.  If I'm going about this all wrong don't be afraid to point me in the right direction.

Comment: You could have an asynctask in the activity that periodically polls the service for the time. Or sync an activity specfic timer up with the service when the Activity resumes.

Comment: I ended up doing this with a service and notification manager.  See the notification manager example code on the android dev site.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a Service, you can read the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html).

Answer (score 0):

It's been referred to as a serious "hack" by a few developers, but I've successfully checked for the back button being pressed so as to successfully clean my project up. I've recently moved most of this code to `onPause()` event because it's called right before the app goes down after back button is pressed. However, if it's really what you desire, it's your program and here's the code I used:

```
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
    killAndReturnParams(0);         
}
```

Again, this method has been talked down before, but I'm pretty sure it's because you're not supposed to override the back button for any reason. The user is supposed to be able to use the back button to return at any point, in any app.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    mActivity.moveTaskToBack(true);
}
```